# Data Column Widths in PHPMyAdmin Display

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there a way in PHPMyAdmin to specify the data column display widths and not have it auto-resize the columns each time I refresh the data? I feel like there's got to be an easy way to do this, but I can't find it anywhere. For example, see my two screenshots. In screenshot 1, I have clicked and dragged the 'input' and 'result' columns to my desired width.

[image: Screenshot 1]

But then as soon as I refresh the data (in screenshot 2), PHPMyAdmin auto-shrinks the 'input' and 'result' column widths and I don't want that...I want it to remember the column widths I specified. Can this be done?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, the answer I found ended up being pretty straight-forward and works for me. I simply added one line of CSS that forced the column widths to always be wider at page load. I found the CSS properties for:

```
.pma_table tbody td span {}
```

and added

```
width: 350px;
```

Where that CSS specification exists will depend on which theme you're using. It also made ALL of the columns 350px in width. I wish I could specify specific columns, but this is better than nothing.

Comment: what are you answering? i am surprised those SO headteachers have not closed your question.